# MFC application (CEditView), The file is too large to open

Tags: c++, mfc

I use MFC application (CEditView) to open 653MB file, the warning message display "The file is too large to open."

I really appreciate if someone could advise me on this issue.

[image]

Comment: [EM_LIMITTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Controls/em-limittext): *"\[...\] the default limit for the amount of text a user can enter in an edit control is 32,767 characters."*

Comment: EM_LIMITTEXT , only 32767 characters. I need to open over 500MB txt file. Any suggestion in visual studio mfc ?

Comment: I already posted a link to the answer. Did you not read it?